# Creating an instance of Leadtools's AutoFormsEngine in Java

Tags: java, leadtools-sdk

I'm trying to use the Leadtools's "[Forms Recognition and Processing SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/forms?SrcOrigin=Google-CPC-forms%20recognition&MatchType=p&AdPos=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmpb0BRCBARIsAG7y4zYkAHJNkxzGvENd3-P7_e0etZQk75j0jhzhBfpAOA84XGqY8NBGwZsaAjY_EALw_wcB)" in a Java application. I have no problem creating an instance of `RasterCodecs`, `OcrEngine` (*OcrEngineManager.createEngine*), `BarcodeEngine` and `DiskMasterFormsRepository`. The last thing that I need to create is an instance of `AutoFormsEngine`, but I get the exception below.

```
leadtools.RasterException: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at leadtools.internal.JavaPlatform.fromBase64String(JavaPlatform.java:7)
    at leadtools.internal.LeadPlatform.fromBase64String(LeadPlatform.java:33)
    at leadtools.forms.recognition.internal.FRForm.readXml(u:389)
    at leadtools.forms.recognition.FormRecognitionAttributes.dataToFRForm(b:297)
    at leadtools.forms.recognition.FormRecognitionEngine.getAttributesManagers(sb:2805)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine$GetFormsManagersCallBack.onMasterFormCallback(wb:1681)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine.k(wb:1441)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine.k(wb:1749)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine.k(wb:3022)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine.k(wb:384)
    at leadtools.forms.auto.AutoFormsEngine.<init>(wb:292)
    at com.ptfs.FormDataExtract.SetupAutoFormsEngine(FormDataExtract.java:241)
    at com.ptfs.FormDataExtract.StartUpEngines(FormDataExtract.java:206)
    at com.ptfs.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
I'm sure the DLL's below are loaded (as I've loaded them manually)

```
ltkrnx.dll
ltdisx.dll
Altfilx.dll
LTIMGUTLx.dll
LTIMGCORx.dll
LTIMGEFXx.dll
LTIMGCLRx.dll
LTDRWx.dll
LTSVGx.dll
LTANNx.dll
LTDOCWRTTTFx.dll
LTDOCWRTEMFx.dll
LTDOCWRTx.dll
LTDRWx.dll
ltocrx.dll
Filters\Lffaxx.dll
Filters\Lfcmpx.dll
Filters\Lftifx.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Apparently Leadtolls will not work with Java SDK 14 and that is what I was using. I downgraded to Java SDK 8 and it worked.